# SSAS Importing Data from SQL Server performance

Tags: sql-server, ssas, ssas-tabular

I've created ssas tabular in import mode. In power query editor, i can import with multiple ways below;

1.

let
Source = #"SQL/localhost;ReportDb",

```
dbo_Fact_Sales = Value.NativeQuery(
#"SQL/localhost;ReportDb",
"SELECT Column1, Column2, Column3 FROM dbo.Fact_Sales WHERE Date_Id >= 20180101 AND Interval_Id = 1")
```

in

```
dbo_Fact_Sales
```

2. 

let
Source = #"SQL/localhost;ReportDb",

```
dbo_Fact_Sales = Source{[Schema="dbo",Item="Fact_Sales"]}[Data]
#"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(dbo_Fact_Sales, each [Interval_Id] = 1),
#"Filtered Rows1" = Table.SelectRows(#"Filtered Rows", each [Date_Id] >= 20180101)
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Filtered Rows1",{"Date_Id","Interval_Id"})
```

in

```
#"Removed Columns"
```

Is there any performance difference between 1 and 2 when refreshing data?

Also, what is the difference between table processing and partition processing?

Comment: If Query folding is taking place, then it should generate roughly the same SQL query in 2 as you define in 1. If you want use the query profiler to see what query is being sent down to the datasource https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-query/power-query-folding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1- The first query seems faster since it retrieves a limited number of columns and a subset of rows.

2- the difference between partition processing and table processing is that:

- Partition processing operations  processes a limited subset of the table which makes it faster and consumes less memory and CPU.
- Table processing operations deal with the entire table and related structures which makes it slower, consumes a lot of  memory and CPU. Processing a table means processing each partition of the table.